# Show ionic spinner in java

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I code a ion-spinner  [ion-spinner](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/) to a Java script. I am using a Appery.io Ionic & AngularJS project? I want to show the spinner when loading a databound list?

Comment: what is the confusion ? use the way Ionic suggest . You want to use it in javascript not in java as your question title says ?

Comment: If you are using angularjs, for display in javascript?